# Showing two norms is not equivalent

Tags: metric-spaces

Define the norms as

$||f||_u=sup_{x\in[a,b]}\{|f(x)|\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ||f||=||f||_u+||f'||_u$

Show that $||\cdot||$ and $||\cdot||_u$ is not equivalent

I've found a sequence for which $||\cdot||_u$ is bounded, but $||\cdot||$ isn't, but I'm thinking I need to show it in a more general case

Comment: If the two norms were equivalent, then for all sequences, bounded for one norm would be equivalent to bounded for the other norm.